# How to use OneToOne with Hibernate Formula

Tags: hibernate

I want to set an `OneToOne` entity using a `Formula`.

I have tried the following but the result is always `null` (I guess because the column `KEY_MEDIA_CONTENT` is always `null`):

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="KEY_MEDIA_CONTENT")
@Formula(value = "SELECT MEDIAASSET_ORDER_ID AS KEY_MEDIA_CONTENT FROM PRODUCTION_MEDIAASSET_NEW WHERE KEY_TEXT=1 AND PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID=PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID")
private MediaAssetOrder keyMediaAsset;
```

It seems like the `Formula` is ignored.

How can I reference an entity using some `Formula`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Formula` is ignored, because it is only valid as replacement for `@Column`. And that one is not used for relationships mappings.

But you can use `@Where` instead, which exists for collections:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "PRODUCTION_MEDIAASSET_NEW", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTION_ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName = "MEDIAASSET_ORDER_ID"))
@Where("KEY_TEXT = 1")
private Collection<MediaAssetOrder> keyMediaAsset;
```

To access your original `keyMediaAsset` object you can use a specific getter:

```
public MediaAssetOrder getKeyMediaAsset() {
  return keyMediaAsset.isEmpty() ? null : keyMediaAsset.iterator().next();
}
```